# mysql UNION duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I understand that using UNION removes duplicate rows in sql, but I want to know how to remove duplicate rows which shares a duplicate primary key with another row. here is the query I have

```
"
SELECT 
    isbn, title, rank, 
    lowest_new_price                AS lowest_price,
    lowest_new_location             AS lowest_location,

    FROM ".TBL_BOOKS."          

UNION

SELECT 
    isbn, title, rank, 
    lowest_used_price               AS lowest_price,
    lowest_used_location            AS lowest_location,

    FROM ".TBL_BOOKS." 


ORDER BY rank ASC"
```

**input data**

```
isbn,    title,    rank,    lowest_new_price,    lowest_new_location
00001    t1        1        100                  uk
00001    t1        1        200                  uk
00002    t3        5        50                   uk
```

**desired output data**

```
isbn,    title,    rank,    lowest_new_price,    lowest_new_location
00001    t1        1        100                  uk
00002    t3        5        50                   uk
```

or

```
isbn,    title,    rank,    lowest_new_price,    lowest_new_location
00001    t1        1        200                  uk
00002    t3        5        50                   uk
```

Comment: Which should take precedence, new or used?  Generally you need to provide your input data, as well as the desired output.  Otherwise difficult to help.

Comment: new or used, any is fine

Comment: You seem to be selecting everything from the same table, why bother with the union? Why not just select all the fields and use a "CASE WHEN" in you select statement?

Comment: @GDF because the tables could become more complicated, books may have the same isbn but will have different prices and condition, each book record in my database has a used_price field and a new_price field, if i want to update book prices I just need one isbn number, but I need to know which books need updating, and this is when I may get two different conditions of the same book requesting an update. this is when I must remove duplicates .Hope that makes any sense

Comment: Essentially you are saying you can have 0..n records with the same ISBN, is this correct? And you want to generate a distinct list of the lowest price for a new, join that to a distinct list of the lowest price for used, is this correct?

Comment: @GDF if by 0..n you mean 0N,1N ....N yes thats correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need two queries, one to get this data into a temporary table, and the second to get the data you want. You can do it in a single query if you want, but it'll be a bit messy.

First, we need the indistinct data by ISBN, as per your query but without the ordering clause - then
Second, we need to get the correct distinct data from it.

Something like this:

```
select data.isbn, data.title, data.rank, min(data.lowest_price) as [Lowest Price], b.lowest_Location
from <your_query> data inner join <your_query> b on data.isbn = b.isbn and data.lowest_price = b.lowest_price
order by data.rank
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following

```
SELECT 
    isbn, title, rank, 
    lowest_new_price                AS lowest_price,
    lowest_new_location             AS lowest_location,

    FROM ".TBL_BOOKS."
    WHERE lowest_new_price <= lowest_used_price

UNION

SELECT 
    isbn, title, rank, 
    lowest_used_price               AS lowest_price,
    lowest_used_location            AS lowest_location,

    FROM ".TBL_BOOKS." 
    WHERE lowest_new_price > lowest_used_price
```

Comment: this is not what im looking for, read the comment i left you above